# Sencha Touch 2 form doesn't submit

Tags: sencha-touch-2

For some reason my form keeps on doing a GET instead of posting the data to the URL I configured.

My form looks like this:

```
Ext.define('App.view.LoginFormPanel', {
extend : 'Ext.form.Panel',
xtype : 'loginForm',
id : 'loginForm',

config : {
    title : 'Login',
    iconCls : 'user',
    ui : 'light',
    items : [
            {
                xtype : 'fieldset',
                title : 'Login',
                items : [
                        {
                            xtype : 'textfield',
                            label : 'Login',
                            name : 'j_username',
                            required : true,
                            readOnly : false
                        }, {
                            xtype : 'passwordfield',
                            label : 'Password',
                            name : 'j_password',
                            required : true,
                            readOnly : false
                        }
                ]
            }, {
                xtype : 'button',
                ui : 'confirm',
                text : 'Login',
                action : 'login'
            }
    ]
}

});
```

And my controller that submits the form looks like this:

```
......
    login : function() {
    loginForm.submit({
        url : 'j_spring_security_check',
        method : 'POST'
    });
},
......
```

I tried to put the url and method on the form too put no luck either :(.

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Do you get any error in the console ?

Comment: No.. There is no error. It just submits the form but does a GET instead

Answer (score 0):

Try to set [standardSubmit](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.form.Panel-cfg-standardSubmit) to true. By default Touch forms are submitted via ajax GET method, but standardSubmit will send POST. Note that parameters will be encoded in http payload, not in the url params.

Cheers, Oleg

Comment: Hi Oleg, I tried setting the standardSubmit to true but unfortunately it still does a GET. Do you have any clue why this is?

Answer (score 0):

My answer is for those who have a problem with submitting a form with POST method.

If you are new to Sencha and you have a form which is submitting nothing, you probably followed this tutorial [Building your first app](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/guide/first_app)

It has a problem. Form items MUST HAVE NAME which is missing in the example.

Items should look something like the following:

```
items: [
{
    xtype: 'textfield',                             
    name: 'name',
    label: 'Name'
},
{
    xtype: 'emailfield',
    name: 'email',
    label: 'Email'
},
{
    xtype: 'textareafield',
    name: 'message',
    label: 'Message'
}
]
```